# Pyspark join doesn't take 5 positional arguments?

Tags: pyspark, left-join, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm implementing LEFT JOIN on 5 columns in Pyspark. But it's throwing an error as shown below

TypeError: join() takes from 2 to 4 positional arguments but 5 were given

Code implemented :

```
Tgt_df_time_in_zone_detail = Tgt_df_view_time_in_zone_detail_dtaas.join(Tgt_df_individual_in_shift_tiz
,Tgt_df_view_time_in_zone_detail_dtaas.id_individual == Tgt_df_individual_in_shift_tiz.id_individual, 
(Tgt_df_view_time_in_zone_detail_dtaas.timestamp_start >= Tgt_df_individual_in_shift_tiz.swipein)
 &   (Tgt_df_view_time_in_zone_detail_dtaas.timestamp_start <= Tgt_df_individual_in_shift_tiz.swipeout)
 & (Tgt_df_view_time_in_zone_detail_dtaas.timestamp_end >= Tgt_df_individual_in_shift_tiz.swipein) 
&(Tgt_df_view_time_in_zone_detail_dtaas.timestamp_end <= Tgt_df_individual_in_shift_tiz.swipeout)
, "left_outer")
```

Why Pyspark doesn't take join on 5 columns? What's the better way to do it then!?

Comment: past what you tried then it will me more clear.

Comment: Hi Rakesh, I've added the Pyspark code with Left Join on 5 columns, but is throwing an error

Comment: Alreay got the answer, missed `&` from condition `()` from first column match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess, you missed **&** in between your 1st and 2nd condition. Try this, if it works.

```
Tgt_df_time_in_zone_detail = Tgt_df_view_time_in_zone_detail_dtaas.join(Tgt_df_individual_in_shift_tiz,
(Tgt_df_view_time_in_zone_detail_dtaas.id_individual == Tgt_df_individual_in_shift_tiz.id_individual)
& (Tgt_df_view_time_in_zone_detail_dtaas.timestamp_start >= Tgt_df_individual_in_shift_tiz.swipein)
& (Tgt_df_view_time_in_zone_detail_dtaas.timestamp_start <= Tgt_df_individual_in_shift_tiz.swipeout)
& (Tgt_df_view_time_in_zone_detail_dtaas.timestamp_end >= Tgt_df_individual_in_shift_tiz.swipein) 
& (Tgt_df_view_time_in_zone_detail_dtaas.timestamp_end <= Tgt_df_individual_in_shift_tiz.swipeout)
, "left_outer")
```